# dynamodb scan through table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table in dynamodb, and the server keeps writing into the table.
In the meanwhile, I use another work thread to keep executing scan on that table, with LastEvaluatedKey. My question is, does the scan eventually get all items from the table? Will it miss any items since other threads are writing into the table day by day.

Thanks,
Yi

Answer (score 1):

yes. in some cases you can miss items.

in hash-range terms, LastEvaluatedKey is actually the last range value seen. dynamo is sorting the response by range value (if in so it sorting it by number, if string it sort the response by the str representation value).

so for example:
if your table values are:

hash , range

1 , 'a'

1 , 'b'

1 , 'c'

1 , 'r'

1 , 'x'

then your first scan can return you ((1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(1,r))
here your LastEvaluatedKey is 'r', and your scan continue from this point

now, if a new item (1,d) inserted into table, it will insert between (1,c) and (1,r), and your scan will miss it, because he continue from (1, r), and will return you (1, x)

so the best solution that i recommend you:

1. [use dynamodb stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) - read with lambda the updates records, and update your new table according to them
2. migration - before running your scan operations, insert a code that write any update/delete to both of your tables, then you can start the scan, and promise not to lose any values.

hope it helps.